# YouTube API/JSON/Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, youtube

Needing your help on something I can't seem to figure out.

I am trying to display my current Youtube Videos via API/JSON and when I go to build project and click the tab that is suppose to build the videos in my view controller I get an error at:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

It highlights:

for item in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {
print(item)

FULL:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

protocol VideoModelDelegate {
    func dataReady()
}

class VideoModel: NSObject {

    var videoArray = [Video]()

    var delegate:VideoModelDelegate?

    func getFeedVideos() {

        let API_KEY = "AIzaSyCvsoQ-MffdpB8ZPw1SSZiS36BbRUMp2cs"
        let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "TLGG_vHch6CEugIxNzAxMjAxOA"
        let CHANNEL_ID = "UC2D6eRvCeMtcF5OGHf1-trw"

        // fetching the videos dinamycally through API
        Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet,contentDetails", "playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID, "key":API_KEY, "channelId":CHANNEL_ID], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

                if let dictionary = JSON as? [String:Any]{

                    for item in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {
                     print(item)

                        //Create video objects off the JSON response
                        let videoObj = Video()
                        videoObj.videoId = Video.value(forKeyPath: "snippet.resourceID.videoId") as! String
                        videoObj.videoTitle = Video.value(forKeyPath: "snipper.tittle") as! String
                        videoObj.videoDiscription = Video.value(forKeyPath: "snippet.description") as! String
                        videoObj.videoThumbnailURL = Video.value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

                        arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
                    }}
                    // When all the video objects have been constucted, assign the array to the VideoModel property
                    self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos

                    //Notify the delegate that the data is ready
                    if self.delegate != nil{
                        self.delegate!.dataReady()
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    func getVideos() -> [Video] {

        //Create a empty array of video objects
        var videos = [Video]()

        // Create a video object
        let video1 = Video()

        //Assign properties
        video1.videoId = "h8onY49kJPo"
        video1.videoTitle = "5-24-11 Canton Lake, Ok longdale tornado EF-3 Blaine County wedge"
        video1.videoDiscription = "***NOT FOR BROADCAST***"

        //Append in into  the videos array
        videos.append(video1)


        // Create a video object
        let video2 = Video()

        //Assign properties
        video2.videoId = "bAM9njN1Llo"
        video2.videoTitle = "8-25-2017 Fulton, TX Hurricane Harvey Extreme, insane incredible wind from eye wall"
        video2.videoDiscription = "***NOT FOR BROADCAST***"

        //Append in into  the videos array
        videos.append(video2)


        // Create a video object
        let video3 = Video()

        //Assign properties
        video3.videoId = "od79-MRWVmA"
        video3.videoTitle = "12-12-2017 Erie, Pa Lake Effect Snow Warning, Historic downtown, heavy snow piling up I-90"
        video3.videoDiscription = "***NOT FOR BROADCAST***"

        //Append in into  the videos array
        videos.append(video3)


        // Create a video object
        let video4 = Video()

        //Assign properties
        video4.videoId = "NxOj10ODtcI"
        video4.videoTitle = "6-15-2017 Great Bend, Ks Gustnado, dust storm, severe thunderstorm"
        video4.videoDiscription = "***NOT FOR BROADCAST***"

        //Append in into  the videos array
        videos.append(video4)


        // Create a video object
        let video5 = Video()

        //Assign properties
        video5.videoId = "vk5o-KSQf9I"
        video5.videoTitle = "3-1-17-Perryville-Mo-tornado-damage-I-55"
        video5.videoDiscription = "***NOT FOR BROADCAST***"

        //Append in into  the videos array
        videos.append(video5)

        //Return the array to the caller
        return videos
    }

}
```

I hope this helps to explain my problem. Still new to coding with only about a year and a half of study (On my own).

My apologies if I have errors on my post as I am new to the group.

Comment: Clearly `dictionary["items"]` is either nil or not an array.

Comment: Still rather new, so how would I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like `dictionary["items"]` is not an Array. Try to use "guard" statement instead of "if". It would be better for debugging

Comment: Could you elaborate how it should look?

Comment: @JoshNapper you can check it in official documentation in "Control Flow" section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120)

Comment: So I'm assuming it's not an easy fix? haha

Comment: I looked over what ya sent, however I'm still just as lost :(

Comment: @JoshNapper for example `if let JSON = response.result.value` you can replace with guard like `guard let JSON = response.result.value else{/*if response.result.value is nil than compiler comes here, if no it moves forward*/}`. And with help of breakpoints it will be much easier to understand you code and there will no so many inherited "if" statements and brackets

Comment: @JoshNapper try also to find out type of `dictionary["items"] ` making breakpoint and type in console `po dictionary["items"].description`